# How To Repeat A Question in A Quiz Game With Different Speech

Tags: bixby

I am trying to create a quiz game that asks a question then plays a short audio file. I would like to give the user the ability to play the audio file again, but without the speech. How would I do this?

Here is my update that asks the question and plays the file:

```
action (UpdateGame) {
  description (Evaluate user's answer and updates the game state.)
  type (UpdateTransaction)
  collect {
    input (state) {
      type (State)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }

    input (fileToPlay) {
      description (Create the playlist to play)
      type (audioPlayer.AudioInfo)
      min (Optional) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: fileAudioInfo
        } 
      }
      hidden
    }

    computed-input (play) {
      description (Ask the client to play our sound.)
      type (audioPlayer.Result)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: audioPlayer.PlayAudio
          value: $expr(fileToPlay)
        }
      }
      hidden
    }

    input (answer){
      type (Answer)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: ChooseAnswer
        } 
      }
    }
  } 

  output (State)
}
```

My State object looks like this:

```
structure (State) {
  description (Holds the game state.)
  features {
    transaction
    transient
  }

  property (game) {
    type (Game)
    min (Required) max (One)
    visibility (Private)
  }

  property (currentQuestion) {
    type (Question)
    min (Required) max (One)
    visibility (Private)
  }

  property (restartQuestion){
    type (RestartQuestion)
    min (Required) max (Many)
    visibility (Private)
  }

  property (completed) {
    type (core.Boolean)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    visibility (Private)
  }

  property (change) {
    type (core.Boolean)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    visibility (Private)
  }

  property (say) {
    type (core.Text)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    description(Should the introductory be read or not?)
  }

  property (display) {
    type (core.Text)
    min (Required) max (One)
    description(Should the introductory be read or not?)
    visibility (Private)
  }
}
```

I have a ReplayAudio action that looks as follows:

```
action (ReplayAudio) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  type (UpdateTransaction)
  collect {
    input (state) {
      type (State)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: ReplayAudio
        } 
      }
      validate {
        replan{
          intent{
            goal: UpdateGame
            value: State {
              currentQuestion: $expr(state.currentQuestion)
              display: $expr(state.display)
              game: $expr(state.game)
              restartQuestion: $expr(state.restartQuestion)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (State)
}
```

So I am trying to omit the `say` field. The issue is, that when I set the say field again in `UpdateGame` it stays blank and I can never reset it.

Why would removing the `say` field, cause it to never be updated again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you can reassign the value of `say` to " " (empty string with only a space), that would be equivalent as no speech.